# How can I see phone emulator while using 3.1 API?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am new in android world. When I create a project while setting `Target = Android 2.3.3 - API Level 10` in my AVD setting, I get following skin options.

[image]

But when I set `Target = Android 3.1 - API Level 12` (which is the latest available) in AVD settings I only get this which is basically tablet version of emulator.

[image]

My question: Does Android 3.1 only supports tablets? (I think answer is Noo)

If No, how can I use API 3.1 with phone version of emulator rather than tablet emulator?

If Yes, can anyone point me to any official statement regarding it?

I have installed the latest android SDK, Eclipse Classic with ADT.

May be setting the Skin -> Resolution will work but is it the only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the docs on screen sizes so you can see the difference.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Yes and I just read your question again... 3.1 is only tablets. Sorry I missed that. I just glanced...

Comment: Is this documented anywhere that what versions of API supports phone and what versions are for tablets?